# Preloading animation for React webpack bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preload

I have a *single page webapp*, which is about 300Kb big. It gets bundled with webpack and uses React/Redux.

How do I put a small loading spinner upfront until the page is loaded? I can image

- putting the style and css into the static *index.html*
- using an async loader like [krux/postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to insert the loading animation in the index.html

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="loader" />
        </div>
        <script src="build/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then after the bundle.js is loaded it will render in the content and the loading animation will disappear.

EDIT:

Another method is to use a progressive webapp.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen

However this feature might only be available in modern browsers, which is why the first approach should be used as a fallback method.
The benefit however is, that if your app is offline it will still play
the loading animation and can give specific error messages.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered with this question with one exception: I wanted to display a loading progress bar. I ended up writing a webpack plugin and a custom asset bootloader. Check out my demo project [repository](https://github.com/rasentry/spa-bootloader).

Here is the result:

[image]