# react, meteor, webpack, es6. How to create a loading/splash screen

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am using a build for react, es6 modules and meteor with webpack.  These techs take a while to load all their stuff, before something shows up on the page.  How can I with this stack show a pre-loader / splash screen while all this loads up?

my webpack file:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './entry'
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json','css','scss']
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    plugins:['transform-runtime'],
                    presets:['es2015','stage-0','react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader:  'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!postcss-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'url?limit=8192',
                    'img-loader'
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]
};
```

My entry.js file:

```
import '../store.js';
import './../lib/routes.jsx';
```

My routes.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlowRouter} from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import {mount} from 'react-mounter';
import $ from 'jquery';
import store from '../store.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import App from '../client/components/app/app.jsx';
import HomePage from '../client/components/pages/home/homePage.jsx';
import AboutPage from '../client/components/pages/about/aboutPage.jsx';
import BlogPage from '../client/components/pages/blog/blogPage.jsx';
import BlogPostPage from '../client/components/pages/blogPost/blogPostPage.jsx';

FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name:"home",
    action() {
        mount(App, {page: <Provider store={store}><HomePage /></Provider>});
    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/about', {
    name:"about",
    action() {
        mount(App, {page: <Provider store={store}><AboutPage /></Provider>});
    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/blog', {
    name:"blog",
    action() {
        mount(App, {page: <Provider store={store}><BlogPage /></Provider>});
    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/blog/:slug', {
    name:"blog post",
    action(params) {
        console.log(params);
        mount(App, {page: <Provider store={store}><BlogPostPage slug={params.slug} /></Provider>});
    }
});

// this is just a work around for a problem I am having with initial rout loading in development mode.
if (!$('.app-root').length)
    FlowRouter.go(window.location.href.replace(/^http(s)?\:\/\/[^:\/\#]*(\:[^\/\#]*)?\/?/,'/').replace(/\#.*$/,'')+'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000));

let lastPage = FlowRouter.current();
store.subscribe(()=>{
    let state = store.getState();
    if (!state || state.currentURL != lastPage)
        FlowRouter.go(state.currentURL);
});
```

Comment: Have not tried anything actually all I keep coming up with is answers for how to do it with meteor native packaging methodology, not when webpack is involved, which pretty much overhauls all that.

Comment: I also cant find anything useful about the webpack config files settings that I could use to achieve this either.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... you mean with live reloading on development? When you push it to production it doesn't really build anything

Comment: I don't really care about the hmr, that is pretty much broken on my current stack anyway (it seems to get very confused when using the es6 modules approach for my react components).  When loading the site up in production a number of resources need to be transferred to the browser for the meteor site to be operational, even with webpacks help, this takes time.  I need to find a way to show a loading screen (simple loader graphic or similar) while all this is happening. Basically adding some initial 'seed' html to the page early on in the load process. Or something similar for a loader to work.

Comment: why not just load a splash screen initially, then use `ReactDOM.render()` to delete the contents of the node and replace it with your application?

Comment: @corvid how would one acheive that? From what i can see the full 'app' needs to load before any of the javascript seems to run.

Comment: yeah, but it will render the HTML, and when the javascript is ready, React will inject it's contents into that div and delete the splash screen (in theory)

Comment: @corvid post ammended with some code

Comment: @corvid So my question at this point is how to get webpack to render an initial html file, since with my webpacks presence meteor doesnt seem to automatically load any html files and templates.

Comment: I found this similar questions to be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299620/preloading-animation-for-react-webpack-bundle

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of research and a lot of help from this thread: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/215

I have discovered that there is no reliable way to do this, at least not what I had in mind.

The solution I used in the end was in my entry file to use the following code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$('body').addClass('css-loading-class-goes-here');

require.ensure(['../store.js', './../lib/routes.jsx'], function(require) {
    require(['../store.js','./../lib/routes.jsx']);
});
```

You can add css, append content or whatever else you want to do at the start there, but this will only execute after alot of the 'native' javascript from webpack and friends has loaded (about 350kb in my case).  Then the require.ensure enforces webpack to load all my app specific javascript in a seperate bundle after the fact, so my 'loader' is at lest active for half of the load process.

This was the only solution that I could find in the end.