# Show loading screen for initial load in React

Tags: reactjs

I have made an eCommerce website with CSR react. In initial load it take much time to load. Because of the load time of bundle.js. 
Now how can I show a loading screen to users while the bundle.js file is loaded.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299620/preloading-animation-for-react-webpack-bundle